# CSS3 rounded corner without using htc

Tags: css

I am trying to get the CSS3 border-radius to work on IE8. But for some reasons, it is not working: http://uiux.atwebpages.com/

I am using the border-radius.htc file.

Is there some other way to make border-radius work on IE8 without using the .htc file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible without using VML just with pure CSS in IE<9. The only other way is to use sliced images. I'd recommend, if those rounded corners are not really necessary, just omit them. It's not your fault, if people use outdated browsers.

However I can recommend you [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/). Take a look at it.

edit:

1. your page has a 404 on css_reset.css
2. Are you sure, your resources have loaded all correctly?
3. you need to include `behavior:url(border-radius.htc)` in your css (with the correct url of course), but i couldn't find this in your css. Try it and see, if it works.

Comment: Thx a lot...I have updated it now on http://uiux.atwebpages.com/skeletal.html ....still does not work..

Answer (score 0):

No, CSS3 border-radius isn't supported in IE8.
Please, refer to this chart for my info about compatibility:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is jQuery an option? If so then try this - http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Answer (score 0):

if you do what's said on this page it should work properly. one more advice: clean up your css and define browser depending rules before you do general css rules.

[css3 in ie](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/)